# object collections with linq

Tags: .net, linq

What are the different collections available to store objects and which one's best to use when? IList, IEnumerate, IQueryable...

I'm new to .net

Thanks.

Comment: Best to use? They exists of different purposes, so what is your purpose? Otherwise, if you just want it general then make it a community wiki :) (would be nice to have a list with them). It should also be noted that a IList is also a IEnumerable and the same with IQueryable. Furthermore, these are only interfaces so you only know the methods of them - not how they are implemented in various collections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find here the documentation for all the collections namespace :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: Yes, but wen I starded with .Net, i was not very comfortable with the documentation : MSDN is such a mess ! And the question is very generic, so, a direct link is not a so bad idea for me...